# Using classes and objects to compute a students GPA

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.totalSumOGrades = 0
        self.numberOGrades = 0

    def getAverageScore(self):
        return (self.totalSumOGrades / self.numberOGrades)

    def addGrade(self,grade):
        self.totalSumOGrades = str(grade)
        self.numberOGrades = self.numberOGrades + 1
        return (self.totalSumOGrades)


class GPA:
    def __init__(self,grade):
        self.grade = grade
        self.score = 0


    def gradesScore(self):
        gradeLetter = self.grade[0]
        gradeSign = ' '
        if (len(self.grade)) == 2:
            gradeSign = self.grade[1]

        if (gradeLetter == 'A'):
            self.score = 4
        elif (gradeLetter == 'B'):
            self.score = 3
        elif (gradeLetter == 'C'):
            self.score = 2
        elif (gradeLetter == 'D'):
            self.score = 1
        elif (gradeLetter == 'F'):
            self.score = 0

        if (gradeSign == '+'):
            self.score += 0.3
        elif (gradeSign == '-'):
            self.score -= 0.3


    def getScore(self):
        self.gradesScore()
        return self.score
```

I need both classes on one sheet. The problem I'm having is the argument that is being taken for class GPA is what "getScore" is calculating. I need it so the addGrade from class student adds a grade and I can have "getScore" calculate those grades instead. How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you use a paper computer :-) ? I do not get the task of "needing two classes on one sheet". THe other prose at the bottom, is this the requirement that if a student already has two grades and a score has been aggregated from these, that if an additional third grade / result is added to his "whatever", that the score aggregate is being recalculated now covereing all three results entered? Suggest to also maybe use a table parser for the few possible valid grades instead of if-elsing your "eyes" off (maybe one could try and compare)  PEP8 helps you learn a lot about Python language.

Comment: ... suggested is to follow that PEP8 in renaming the student class to Student and last but not least: What is a GPA (I am no US American) as class it might be better to Camel Case it out (what it means). To not forget: stating the most important: Good start for us to help I think, as you really try something and show it. Thanks.

Comment: Grade Point Average...

Answer (score 1):

So as I promised an answer / feedback version to help the OP walk through and pick some new questions - here it is (offered in the hope that train hacking is sufficiently high quality to show case some concepts and offer agood start to create a real solution based on this):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division, print_function


class GradePointAverage(object):
    """Implements a "Grade Point Average" (GPA) calculation.
    Note: It keeps all grades to offer an incremental update path.
    """

    FILL_CHAR_ZERO_ADJUST = '.'
    VALID_LETTERS = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
    VALID_ADJUSTMENTS = ('+', FILL_CHAR_ZERO_ADJUST, '-')

    BASE_SCORE_MAP = dict(zip(reversed(VALID_LETTERS), (0., 1., 2., 3., 4.)))
    ADJ_SCORE_MAP = dict(zip(VALID_ADJUSTMENTS, (0.3, 0., -0.3)))

    def __init__(self, grades=None):
        """Inintializes the _grades, a sequence of canonical grade
        values e.g. ['A+', 'B-'] where any grade recieved is
        mapped to uppercase letter plus either ''|'+'|'-' or
        and exception ValueError is thrown.
        """
        if grades is None:
            self._grades = list()
        else:
            self._grades = [self.canonicalize_grade(g) for g in grades]

    def __repr__(self):
        """Helper to (de)serialize and put more in print et al."""
        return ('GradePointAverage(%s)' % (str(self._grades)))

    def add_grades(self, grades):
        """Add a new result / grade to data."""
        for g in grades:
            self.add_grade(g)

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        """Add a new result / grade to data."""
        self._grades.append(self.canonicalize_grade(grade))

    def count_grades(self):
        """Return the count of grades, the scoring is based upon."""
        return len(self._grades)

    def grades(self):
        """Return the grades as list, the scoring is based upon."""
        return self._grades

    def canonicalize_grade(self, grade):
        """Ensure grade is valid, ensure uppercase letter plus either
        ''|'+'|'-' on output. If invalid, let raise or throw ValueError. """
        c_grade = grade.strip().upper()  # May raise
        if 1 <= len(c_grade) <= 2:
            if len(c_grade) < 2:
                c_grade += self.FILL_CHAR_ZERO_ADJUST
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid grade length")

        if c_grade[0] not in self.VALID_LETTERS:
            raise ValueError("Invalid main grade")

        if c_grade[1] not in self.VALID_ADJUSTMENTS:
            raise ValueError("Invalid grade adjustment")

        return c_grade

    def _score(self, canonical_grade):
        """Calculate score from canonical grade."""
        base, adj = canonical_grade[0], canonical_grade[1]
        return self.BASE_SCORE_MAP[base] + self.ADJ_SCORE_MAP[adj]

    def average_score(self):
        """Calculate average score."""
        if not self.count_grades():
            return None
        # implicit else:
        score_sum = sum(self._score(c_g) for c_g in self._grades)
        return score_sum / float(self.count_grades())

    def median_score(self):
        """Calculate median score."""
        if not self.count_grades():
            return None
        # implicit else:
        middle_index = self.count_grades() // 2
        return sorted([self._score(c_g) for c_g in self._grades])[middle_index]

    def best_score(self):
        """retrieve highest score."""
        return NotImplemented


class Student:
    """Models student with updateable Grade Point Average."""
    def __init__(self, grades):
        self._gPA = GradePointAverage(grades)
        self.number_of_grades = self._gPA.count_grades()

    def __repr__(self):
        """Helper to (de)serialize and put more in print et al."""
        return ('Student(%s)' % (str(self._gPA.grades())))

    # Delegated / proxy methods
    def average_score(self):
        return self._gPA.average_score()

    def count_grades(self):
        return self._gPA.count_grades()

    def grades(self):
        return self._gPA.grades()

    def median_score(self):
        return self._gPA.median_score()

    def best_score(self):
        return self._gPA.best_score()

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        return self._gPA.add_grade(grade)

    def add_grades(self, grades):
        return self._gPA.add_grades(grades)


def main():
    """Drive some tests on "scored" Students."""

    print('Positive test cases:')
    print('... service class under test:')
    gPA = GradePointAverage(['a+', 'c-'])
    print(gPA)

    print('... main class under test:')
    student = Student(['F+'])
    print(student)
    print(student.count_grades())
    print(student.average_score())
    print(student.median_score())
    a_grade = 'E-'
    print("Added %s" % (a_grade,))
    student.add_grade('E-')
    print(student.count_grades())
    print(student.average_score())
    print(student.median_score())

    some_grades = ['E', 'b+', 'b-', 'c+', 'D', 'D']
    print("Added %s" % (str(some_grades),))
    student.add_grades(some_grades)
    print(student.count_grades())
    print(student.average_score())
    print(student.median_score())
    print(student.grades())

    print('Negative test cases:')

    print(student.best_score())

    print('... too long:')
    try:
        _ = GradePointAverage(['aa+', 'no_impact'])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    print('... wrong grade letter:')
    try:
        _ = GradePointAverage(['z', 'no_impact'])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    print('... wrong adjustment:')
    try:
        _ = GradePointAverage(['A*', 'no_impact'])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

    print('... wrong grade "type" we did let it just bubble:')
    try:
        _ = GradePointAverage([42, 'no_impact'])
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So a student instance always delegates grade and score related tasks to the member instance of the GradePointsAverage class. This shifts the Student class close to ebing a superfluous layer (as is) but in reality you would now stuff personal info identifying the student being modelled into the Student instance.

When I run above code on my machine (with a python v2 interpreter):

```
Positive test cases:
... service class under test:
GradePointAverage(['A+', 'C-'])
... main class under test:
Student(['F+'])
1
0.3
0.3
Added E-
2
0.5
0.7
Added ['E', 'b+', 'b-', 'c+', 'D', 'D']
8
2.1625
2.0
['F+', 'E-', 'E.', 'B+', 'B-', 'C+', 'D.', 'D.']
Negative test cases:
NotImplemented
... too long:
Invalid grade length
... wrong grade letter:
Invalid main grade
... wrong adjustment:
Invalid grade adjustment
... wrong grade "type" we did let it just bubble:
'int' object has no attribute 'strip'
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

One should IMO not over engineer toy problems, but this one might offer interesting extension tasks, like storing a hash/anonymized id with the student instances. That would match more real life, where the storage of data that might allow identification of a person or might have the potential to disclose private details of a person is often split into spreading salted hashes to attach to all class instances that need a back reference, but keep the mapping back to ther real names, dates and places etc. in one especially secure place only.

Also maybe introduce (besides the added median) also min/max i.e. worst/best score or grade "info" from any student instance, maybe even try a simple linear regression on the scores to find some "trend".

Another class of extensions would be trying to "cover" all paths in tests.

A further way to "blow things up" might be, a more elgant mini language internal mapping, where the "collection stages" (those mapping from grades to numeric values) are fully transformed to integers eg. by scaling all by a factor of ten and so have lossless arithmetics, with the price to think about "reporting" the expected back transformed real scores (i.e. as sample 4.3 and not 43) but also have the benefit of reporintg easily the grade representation from any score and remebering to only perform one final "rounding" step.

Note also that the helpful pep8 tool or e.g. `python3 -m pep8 so_get_gpa_for_student_edited.py` gives neither errors nor warnings.

Another hint, often during development and when extending objects / adding fetaures, the names slowly drift out of bounds. Until now (to me) `GradePointAverage` is a matching class / type name, as I often accept a median in comparison to an arithmetic average as a usefull twin information. But if I already had entered say. a trend method, then it would have been a good time to further separate the functionality or rename the class.

Also deciding on a consisten error strategy helps a lot. In above code we mostly state the problem class, but eg. do not report back what exactly caused the problem. In many cases this is ok or even wanted, but in other cases one might add some detail to the response.

One last detail: Just so you know how to first define all interface methods, and second implement these one by one while incrementally testing I also added one of the tricks to signal when somethig is planned, but not (yet) implemented. Here I simply return `NotImplemented`in the best_score method. One might also `raise NotImplementedError("Method_best_score")` instead, but as this leads to:

```
  File "/Users/sthagen/tmp/so_get_gpa_for_student_edited.py", line 184, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sthagen/tmp/so_get_gpa_for_student_edited.py", line 157, in main
    print(student.best_score())
  File "/Users/sthagen/tmp/so_get_gpa_for_student_edited.py", line 117, in best_score
    return self._gPA.best_score()
  File "/Users/sthagen/tmp/so_get_gpa_for_student_edited.py", line 90, in best_score
    raise NotImplementedError("Method best_score")
NotImplementedError: Method best_score
```

I often during active creation from "zero" the more silent `return NotImplemented` option and in (pre-)production when a call to a not yet implemented method or function is more probable an error in usage, I switch to the Exception, your mileage may vary ...

Please feel free to comment (in case I misread the task) or if I forgot to comment on a change you notice when comparing to your code smaple.